# Act on a `case` clause in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, compilation, functional-programming

I'm attempting [problem 11](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20) of "99 Haskell Problems." The problem description is pretty much:

> Write a function `encodeModified` that groups consecutive equal elements, then counts each group, and separates singles from runs.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Prelude> encodeModified "aaaabccaadeeee"
> [Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c',
>  Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']
> ```

Here's my working code:

```
module Batch2 where

import Data.List -- for `group`
data MultiElement a = Single a | Multiple Int a deriving (Show)

encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f xs = case length xs of 1 -> Single (head xs)
                                 _ -> Multiple (length xs) (head xs)
```

I'd like to take out that pesky repeated `(head xs)` in the final two lines. I figured I could do so by treating the result of the `case` clause as a partially applied data constructor, as follows, but no luck:

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f xs = case length xs of 1 -> Single
                                 _ -> Multiple length xs 
               (head xs)
```

I also tried putting parenthese around the `case` clause itself, but to no avail. In that case, the `case` clause itself failed to compile (throwing an error upon hitting the `_` symbol on the second line of the clause).

> **EDIT**: this error was because I added a parenthesis but didn't add an extra space to the next line to make the indentation match. Thanks, [raymonad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643230/act-on-a-case-clause-in-haskell/23643369#comment36310022_23643230).

I can also solve it like this, but it seems a little messy:

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map (\x -> f x (head x)) . group
  where f xs = case length xs of 1 -> Single
                                 _ -> Multiple (length xs)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can indeed treat the result of the case as a partially applied function. The entire case statement must be in parentheses.

Comment: Hmm—I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/nt5drnut) and got an error ``parse error on input `_'``?

Comment: @WChargin That's because the `_` doesn't line up with the `1` from the other alternative.

Comment: @raymonad Ah! That makes sense. T
hanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function application operator `$` can be used to make this work:

```
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f xs = case length xs of 1 -> Single
                                 _ -> Multiple (length xs)
               $ head xs
```

Answer (score 3):

You could match on `xs` itself instead:

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f xs = case xs of (x:[]) -> Single x
                          (x:_)  -> Multiple (length xs) x
```

or more tersely as

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f (x:[]) = Single x
        f xs@(x:_)  = Multiple (length xs) x
```

or even

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f as@(x:xs) = case xs of [] -> Single x
                                 _  -> Multiple (length as) x
```

Admittedly most of these have some repetition, but not of function application.

You could also go with `let`:

```
encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [MultiElement a]
encodeModified = map f . group
  where f xs = let x   = head xs 
                   len = length xs in 
        case len of 1 -> Single x
                    _ -> Multiple len x
```

Comment: Are you missing an `xs@` in the pattern for the second case in the terse version?

Comment: Thanks. This is more concise. However, it's just hiding the `head xs` as the `x` in `(x:[])`.

Comment: Yes, but at least it doesn't calculate it twice. Your `$ head xs` solution is nice, so I upvoted it.

Comment: And it also avoids calculating `length xs` twice.

Comment: @WChargin: Also, if that pattern match fails it gives you a nice error message that tells you what line of code failed. If you do `head []` all it says is `*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`. You should always try to prefer pattern matching over using partial functions. `(x:[])` could be a little shorter though, as `[x]`.

Comment: @raymonad I was under the impression that Haskell (or at least GHC) would "store" the value of `length xs`, much like memoization, so that it *wouldn't* have to be calculated twice? Isn't this what makes Fibonacci numbers (like `fibs=0:1:zipWith(+)fibs (tail fibs)`) efficient/non-exponential?